# Null and Alternative Hypothesis

Tags: statistics

My task for the 2 following problems is to identify the null value and alternative value. I know similar questions have been asked, and I've looked at them and I think I understand it. But I keep getting this question wrong

Question 1: Perform hypothesis test for population proportion

It is known that 29% of the months have rice production by Company1 above 307200 cwt (company1>307200.0). Is there sufficient evidence to suggest that the proportion is less than 29%? Test at 5% level of significance.

My answer:
Null = .29
alternative = .01

Question 2: Perform hypothesis test for population mean
It is claimed that average rice production by Company2 is 209,500 cwt (Company2 = 209500.0). Test this claim using a hypothesis test at 1% level of significance.

My answer:
Null = 209500.0
alternative = .01

I'm being told that these my answers are not correct. I have no idea why. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Your formatting for this is incorrect, Null is not equal to 0.29, The correct way to state this is Null: p = 0.29, Also why are you saying alternative = 0.1? I can understand what you meant by the incorrect notation, but they are asking if the proportion is less than 29%, where did the 0.01 come from? 
Alternative should be p < 0.29  
(Someone please correct me if I am wrong, It has been a while since I've done applied statistics)

Comment: Sorry! I messed that up, In question one I believe the alternative = .05. I was under the impression that if you have a specific test case (such as the .05) that that was the alternative value

Comment: $0.05$ and $0.01$ are the levels of significance of the tests but not the alternative hypotheses.

Answer (score 1):

Some hints to get you started:

**For Question 1:**
Event:  For Company 1 rice production > 307200.0
$p = P(Event).$ Null hypothesis $H_0: p \ge 0.29$ and
alternative hypothesis $H_a: p < 0.29.$ You may choose to test at the significance level $\alpha = 0.05 = 5\%,$ which will determine the critical value. I have no idea
where your got 0.01.

*Note:* The null hypothesis must always contain an $=$-sign in some way: perhaps $\le, \ge,$ or simply $=.$

**For Question 2.** $H_0:  \mu = 209500.0;$ alternative has $\ne.$